# Using Eloquent relations without calling ->get()

Tags: php, oop, laravel, eloquent

So I have a model called `Pricetag`, which has a OneToMany relationship with `Price`.

I can get all `prices` from a `Pricetag` with this function:

```
public function prices(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Price');
}
```

and by calling it like this: `$pricetag->prices;`

This is all very basic. Eloquent automatically calls the `->get()` function on a function when using it as an `attribute`.

Now for my question:

If I want to be able to get the current price (as the price object, not a collection of prices) from a pricetag by calling `->price` without calling the `->first()` on it... How would I go about that?

I've got the following code right now:

```
public function price($date = null){
    if($date === null){
        $date = Carbon::now();
    }
    return $this->prices()->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->where('date', '<=', $date);
}
```

When called like this `$pricetag->price` it returns a collection of prices.

When called like this `$pricetag->price()->first()` it returns the first price as the `price` object.

How can I get it so it returns the object when calling it like an attribute? Or is that where the attribute 'syntax' ends and I need to just use a method like `->getPrice()`

**EDIT** Found a clean solution!

I made a trait called `History` which looks like this:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

    trait History {
        public $current_date = null;

        public function when($date){
            $this->current_date = $date;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getDateAttribute(){
            return $this->current_date === null ? Carbon::now() : $this->current_date;
        }
    }
```

which will allow me to call the `$pricetag->price` attribute for the current price without a hitch. And if I want to get the price of tomorrow or yesterday or any time I'd just call it like this `$pricetag->when($date)->price`!

The functions inside the `Model` which need the date for filtering can just call `$this->date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test the code, but try this on your `Pricetag` model:

```
 public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        $date = Carbon::now();
        return $this->prices()->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->where('date', '<=', $date)->first();
    }
```

Now try calling `$pricetag->price`. Let me know what you get.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) I still have to call `->get()` but can't pass another date in as a parameter, so it doesn't work. Still thanks though :)

Comment: Changed the answer to avoid calling `->get()` again. :) But I don't think you can pass a parameter when you want to call it like `$pricetag->price`.

Comment: No I'm afraid I can't pass a parameter in like that. I want to be able to do that so I can get the price of a product that isn't today's price. I think I'll go with the `->getPrice($date = null)`.  :)

Comment: Yes. so I think you can use both this one and the `getPrice($date=null)`. Use the `->price` whenever you want the current price (which is most the cases I believe) and in the other cases you can use the other method. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: That sounds like the right thing to do, for the sake of consistency :) I removed the `if($date === null)` check, because you'll call the function only when specifying a date and the `getPriceAttribute()` just returns the `getPrice(Carbon::now())`. Which works great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: I have another idea! What if I add a date attribute to `Pricetag` and every query filters according to that attribute if it's not set to `null`? I think that would be even more flexible, because I have the same configuration for `Taxes`, so if you want the price with tax, bot the price and the tax can filter with one date.. If that makes sense :p

Comment: :) try and win bro, try and win :) let me know if that works.

Comment: I have a solution which I'm satisfied with, check out my edited question above I've you're interested :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought so! P.S. If* :p

Answer (score 1):

It is unconventional to use parameters with relationship methods/attributes, but you should be able to get the logic you're looking for like this:

```
public function price($date = null) {
    if ($date === null) {
        $date = Carbon::now();
    }

    return $this->hasOne('App\Price')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->where('date', '<=', $date);
}
```

By defining it as a `hasOne`, the attribute will return the object, not a Collection. When you access the attribute, you will always get the latest price (since you can't pass in a parameter), but if you use the relationship method, you can pass in the date for which you'd like to constrain:

```
// latest price
$price = $pricetag->price;

// other price
$otherPrice = $pricetag->price($someDate)->first();
```